# what does a negative logloss value indicate

Tags: python, loss-functions

I am using logloss python function provided [here](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss) and I am getting results as -2.99 when I use a machine learning algorithm on my dataset. What does that mean? The algorithm's predictions are bad (or) good? How good or bad?

This is the code I am using. (New to python as well, so maybe my inputs to the function are totally wrong?)

```
    dataset = pd.read_csv('../training.csv')

    cols = dataset[dataset.columns]
    cols.drop(['tobepredicted'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    cols.drop('ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    features = cols.columns

    target = dataset['tobepredicted']
    train = dataset[features]
    cfr = SVR(C=100, kernel="poly", degree=3)

    #Simple K-Fold cross validation. 5 folds.
    cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train), n_folds=5)

    N = len(dataset)
    l = range(N)

    results = []
    for traincv, testcv in cv:
        trainLen = len(traincv)
        shuffle(l)
        probas = cfr.fit(train.ix[l[:trainLen]], target.ix[l[:trainLen]]).predict(train.ix[l[trainLen:]])
        results.append(llfun(target.ix[l[trainLen:]], probas))
    #print out the mean of the cross-validated results
    print "Results: " + str(np.array(results).mean())
```

Comment: The formula you link to can never be negative when supplied with valid input, so how are you obtaining $-2.99$?

Comment: Did you realise that the equation has a minus sign?

Answer (score 2):

The contribution of the $i$th point to the likelihood is $\mathcal{L}_i = p{_i}^{y_i} (1-p_i)^{1-{y_i}}$ which is either $p_i$ or $1-p_i$, both of which are probabilties, so at most they can be $1$ and in practical situations of interest nearly always less than $1$ (and more than $0$, naturally).

Consequently $\log(\mathcal{L}_i)\leq 0$. A sum of non-positive numbers is also non-positive, so $-\sum_i \log(\mathcal{L}_i)$ must be non-negative. For it to be able to be negative would require that a point can contribute a likelihood greater than $1$ but this is not possible with the Bernoulli.

(i.e. just as whuber said, it can never be negative; the negative sign applied to a Bernoulli log-likelihood makes the result non-negative)

Answer (score 0):

scikit implements metrics this way so that larger is better (i.e., to maximize score). GridSearchCV always tries to maximize scores.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you include an explanation of how this comment addresses the question concerning what the loss means and whether it's good or bad?  (It's not clear how it addresses those issues.)

Comment: Does that mean +100 good and -2.99 is very bad? Should I try a different algorithm than SVR to see if I get score of high +ve number and pick the algo that gives the highest +ve number as best algorithm for predicting values on this dataset?